# Fitting a multivariate T Copula to three variables in R

Tags: r, fitting, t-distribution, copula

I have three variables with correlation coefficient of respectively 0.3; -0.2 and 0.1.
I want to fit a T copula but when I use the fitCopula function it gives me a single value for rho, which leads to a poor fit to the data.

```
 zCop<-tCopula(dim=3) 
set.seed(500)
m <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(IG, HY,GOV)))
fit <- fitCopula(zCop,m,method='ml')
coef(fit)


 rho.1         df 
0.06940047 6.30347241
```

I have tried to fit bivariate copulas for each couple, and in that case the rho is close to the empirical one, but I get very different results for the df which can only be a single parameter.

When I do IG,HY I get the following, which is close to the empirical correlation:

```
zCop<-tCopula(dim=2) 
set.seed(500)
m <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(IG,HY)))
cor(m, method="spearman")

fit <- fitCopula(zCop,m,method='ml')
coef(fit)
 rho.1         df 
 0.3417333 10.6678394
```

I wonder whether I could impose the correlation structure and then use the df estimated from the multivariate copula (6.3 here) as down below (weher coef1 is the rho fitted for IG-HY, coef2 for IG-GOV and coef3 for HY-GOV)

```
u <- rCopula(3965,tCopula(dim=3,c(coef1,coef2,coef3),df=6.3,dispstr='un'))
```

I wonder whether I could use this:

```
zCop<-tCopula(dim=3, dispstr = 'un') 
set.seed(500)
m <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(IG, HY,GOV)))
fit <- fitCopula(zCop,m,method='itau.mpl')
coef(fit)

      rho.1       rho.2       rho.3          df 
 0.33823924 -0.19170082  0.07088704 13.89581598
```

Comment: What is matrix 'm' return?

Comment: matrix M is the matrix created by converting data from IG, HY amd GOV into pseudo observations, see also  (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355085/when-modeling-a-copula-you-need-to-generate-pseudo-observations-why-what-is)

Comment: Do you want a t-copula or just t-distributed marginals?

Answer (score 2):

**I have tried to fit bivariate copulas for each couple**

The nice way to model multivariate data fitting bivariate copula for each pair of variables is using pair-copula models. Pair-copula models fit only bivariate copula (pair-copula) for each pair of variables at a time. Using VineCopula or CDvine packages you can nicely fit a C-vine model (one sub-class) of pair-copula models to your data using only t-copula family. As you did not provide your data, then I cannot help you with further information about the R code. Try one of the two listed packages. I am happy to help if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to set the `dispstr` argument of `tCop` to 'un'

In the first line of your example code you omit the `dispstr` argument, which causes it to take its default value of `'ex'`.  This specifies an exchangeable copula, so you get only a single rho value.  Specifying `'un'` allows you to fit a t-copula with an arbitrary covariance matrix.

Here's an example:

```
cormat <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, -0.1, 0.3, 1, 0.2, -0.1, 0.2, 1), nrow=3)
xtest <- rmvt(1000, cormat, df=4)
utest <- pobs(xtest)
tcop <- tCopula(dim=3, dispstr='un', df.fixed=FALSE)            # This line is the key
fit <- fitCopula(tcop, utest)
```

When you print fit afterward you get:

```
Call: fitCopula(copula, data = data)
Fit based on "maximum pseudo-likelihood" and 1000 3-dimensional observations.
Copula: tCopula 
  rho.1   rho.2   rho.3      df 
 0.2538 -0.1047  0.1662  3.9508 
The maximized loglikelihood is 127.7 
Optimization converged
```

Note, however, that when fitting an elliptical copula to a dataset you can only have a single `df` parameter for the copula.  If you want the `df` to be different for each pair, then you could fit a pair copula construct, as explained in the answer by Mary.  Alternatively, you could use a grouped t-copula, as described in example 3.1.10 (pp. 95-97) of *Elements of Copula Modeling with R*, by Hofert, et al.